# How to custom style a button from a library?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm using a button from a library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google I understand this library has a custom button option but this option results in a different response).

I basically like to change the max-width and width to another value (image attached below). May I know is there a way for me to edit these style from CSS?

Thank you! Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google adds this button to the dom inside iframe, there are certain props you can style the button

to add with, check prop width on 
it's mentioned on @react-oauth/google github README
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#width

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that as well but they seem to limit the max width to 400px. Can't seem to change that...

Answer (score 0):

So still new myself currently in a full stack boot camp in the react section. It should be possible.

Are you using a external stylesheet or trying to do it using inline?

I was taught to use a external stylesheet
From what I am seeing try changing class name to button.

```
class='button'
```

Then in your external stylesheet add

```
.button {
max-width: 400px;
}
```

Edit. I see you are using react... So it could be className='button'

Edit:

> Hello, thanks for your reply! Hmm... in this case I am not able to
> assign a className to div myself as the div is from the library. The
> weird class you see above "nsm7Bb..." is not by me. Hence, I was
> wondering if there's a way to forcefully override library class style.
> –  Olympian Collections

Gotcha.

Have you tried `!important`?

Is that your inline CSS?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! Hmm... in this case I am not able to assign a className to div myself as the div is from the library. The weird class you see above "nsm7Bb..." is not by me.

Hence, I was wondering if there's a way to forcefully override library class style.

Comment: @OlympianCollections updated post. Have you tried `!important`?